# How to vlookup an entire column on VBA instead of a single cell?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a vlookup vba code that looks like the following. In the `Set lookFor = book1.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 6)` section, I want to lookup and return values for the entire column until there are no more populated values left, instead of selecting a single cell every time.

Any suggestions?

```
Sub VlookMultipleWorkbooks()

Dim lookFor As Range
Dim srchRange As Range

Dim book1 As Workbook
Dim book2 As Workbook

Dim book2Name As String
book2Name = "Rates.xlsx"    'modify it as per your requirement

Dim book2NamePath As String
book2NamePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & book2Name

Set book1 = ThisWorkbook

If IsOpen(book2Name) = False Then Workbooks.Open (book2NamePath)

Set book2 = Workbooks(book2Name)
Set lookFor = book1.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 6) ' value to find
Set srchRange = book2.Sheets(1).Range("A:C")    'source

lookFor.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(lookFor, srchRange, 2, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: Vlookup can only return one value, so what are you expecting if you search for many values at the same time?

Comment: I want the code to search for each value without having to write it out manually as I have 40000+ rows that I need to vlookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the only "problem" your code currently has is that you are executing it for one cell only but want it to be executed for all cells in the column.

So when you write

```
Set lookFor = book1.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 6) ' value to find
Set srchRange = book2.Sheets(1).Range("A:C")    'source
lookFor.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(lookFor, srchRange, 2, False)
```

you'd have to continue

```
Set lookFor = book1.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 6) ' value to find
lookFor.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(lookFor, srchRange, 2, False)
Set lookFor = book1.Sheets(1).Cells(4, 6) ' value to find
lookFor.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(lookFor, srchRange, 2, False)
Set lookFor = book1.Sheets(1).Cells(5, 6) ' value to find
lookFor.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(lookFor, srchRange, 2, False)
```

etc.

So basically all you need is a loop over `r = 2 To <LAST_ROW_NUM>` and use `Set lookFor = book1.Sheets(1).Cells(r, 6)`:

```
Sub VlookMultipleWorkbooks()

  Dim lookFor As Range
  Dim srchRange As Range

  Dim book1 As Workbook
  Dim book2 As Workbook

  Dim book2Name As String
  book2Name = "Rates.xlsx"    'modify it as per your requirement

  Dim book2NamePath As String
  book2NamePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & book2Name

  Set book1 = ThisWorkbook

  If IsOpen(book2Name) = False Then Workbooks.Open (book2NamePath)

  Set book2 = Workbooks(book2Name)
  Set srchRange = book2.Sheets(1).Range("A:C")    'source

  Dim r As Long
  Dim lastRow As Long

  ' Gets the row num of the last filled row
  lastRow = book1.Sheets(1).Range("F" & book1.Sheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  For r = 2 To lastRow
    Set lookFor = book1.Sheets(1).Cells(r, 6) ' value to find    
    lookFor.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(lookFor, srchRange, 2, False)
  Next r

End Sub
```

Just as a quick note: if you want this to be updated live and not just filled out once, you need to actually set the `FormulaR1C1` property to a string containing the English formula. By using R1C1 notation, you can assign the VLOOKUP formula to the whole range at once instead of iterating over all cells.

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed and the lastRow is a nice feature, instead of setting it to the total number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not clear. But I probably understand what you want to achieve. Here is an example I wrote- adapt it to your case. Simply we store our ranges in arrays, then for each element we use vlookup VBA function and in the end we put array data to specified range.

```
 Option Explicit
 Option Base 1

 Sub VlookMultipleWorkbooks()

      ' change this data to yours
       Dim rng1 As Range ' values to find
       Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A1000")

       Dim rng2 As Range ' vlookup range 
       Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1:B1000")

       Dim rngTarget As Range ' where to put your data
       Set rngTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1:B1000")

       ' because a lot of data you have
       ' instead inserting FormulaR1C1 into sheet
       ' I prefere use arrays 
       Dim arrRng1 As Variant
           arrRng1 = rng1.Value

       Dim arrRng2 As Variant
           arrRng2 = rng2

       Dim i As Long ' counter
       For i = 1 To UBound(arrRng1)
         arrRng1(i, 1) = Application.VLookup(arrRng1(i, 1), arrRng2, 2, False)
       Next i

       rngTarget = arrRng1

    End Sub
```